# how does $x_1y_1-x_1y_2-x_2y_1+3x_2y_2$ become an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I would appreciate assistance to my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792605/how-does-a1x1-x1y2-x2y13x2y2-become-an-inner-product

I do not understand where the negative terms come from and where does the 3 come from? Assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: An inner product does not have to be $x_1y_1+x_2y_2$. In this problem, it is defined to be the one as you had. The problem asks you to show whether it satisfies the 3 properties of inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is a vector space over the real numbers, an inner product is a function of two arguments, usually written $\langle x, y \rangle$ for the inner product of the vectors $x, y \in V$. It has to satisfy the following properties:

1. Symmetry: $\langle x, y \rangle = \langle y, x \rangle$.
2. Linearity in the first argument:

   - $\langle \alpha x, y \rangle = \alpha \langle x, y \rangle$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$
   - $\langle x_1 + x_2, y \rangle = \langle x_1, y \rangle + \langle x_2, y\rangle$.
3. Positive definiteness:

   - $\langle x, x \rangle \geq 0$
   - $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.

Note that linearity in the second argument follows from 1 and 2 together.

So to show that
$$\left\langle \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix} \right\rangle = x_1y_1 - x_1y_2 - x_2y_1 + 3x_2y_2$$
is an inner product, you only need to show that these three properties hold.

I am guessing this is from some kind of exercise. I would suspect that the point of the exercise is to drive home the point that an inner product does not need to be the one everyone learns, but can take on other forms and still have the properties one needs for it to work nicely.

In general, if $M$ is a positive-definite symmetric matrix, then the function that takes two arguments $x$ and $y$, defined by $y^TMx$, is an inner product, i.e. satisfies the properties above.

Comment: Thanks @Calle, this is actually a solved problem in the Schaum's series linear algebra textbook. It is only that I could not follow where the minuses and 3x2y2 were coming from. Now if it is a question of showing symmetry, from property I, I will go over again. thanks all the same.

Comment: I don't think they are supposed to come from a special place, it's just that if you pick these numbers, it might be an inner product. You could just as well pick, say $2x_1y_1 - x_1y_2 - x_2y_2 + 3x_1x_2$, and check if that defines an inner product.

Comment: And don't forget to check the positive definiteness!

Comment: Once more thanks very much, at least i have learnt that an inner product, in the sense of vector spaces is not necessarily restricted to the dot product of geometric vectors, but is more general and applicable to integrals, matrices  and many other branches of mathematics.